# go from block back to image + blockproc

Tags: matlab

I need to visualize the output from blockproc. I use this function to get a label for all the blocks. I want to now set each block in the image to the corresponding label in the output.

The code is given below:

```
Feature = blockproc( image , [ 8 8 ] , fun ); 
%where image is a binary image and fun gives 1 label either 0 or 1 to each block

%% Now for each block I want to do the reverse - set the corresponding image coords to 
%% the feature output
```

I figured I can call another blockproc which will set the images to the corresponding Feature values. But I am having trouble doing this.

```
%% fun = @(block_struct) block_struct.data = Feature ( counter ) // counter = block no.
```

Any way to do the above ?

Comment: Is the problem that your initial function returns a single value for each block, so `Feature` is not the same size as `image`, but you'd like it to be?

Comment: No, I just want to visualize the output. I know that Feature will be the size of the number of blocks. So for a 128 X 128 image, I will have 256 blocks of 8X8 size with just 1 label per block. Now, I want to reconstruct the image from these blocks setting each block to the label value.

Comment: It's not really "reconstruction" if all you need to do is resize the output.

Comment: @nkjt Call it resizing then :) My initial image was also a binary image so I am hoping it will be a reconstruction of a sort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `fun` takes a block and returns a single label, you can instead make it return a block of the same size as the input as shown in the [documentation example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/blockproc.html).

```
fun = @(block_struct) ...
   std2(block_struct.data) * ones(size(block_struct.data));
```

Then your `Feature` will be the same size as the original image.

Alternatively, you can just resize the output - either use `imresize` with `nearest` or this will do it:

```
Feature2 = kron(Feature, ones(8));
```

Comment: The label could either be 1 or 0 so the second method would not work. The first thing you suggested may work. I will check it out before accepting...

Comment: Do you know what `kron` **does**? If not, maybe you should check that before telling me it won't work.

Comment: A little less hostility would be appreciated. Did not mean to say anything negative. I had to tweak the first function by multiplying it with the actual label and it worked. Thanks for your efforts..

Comment: Well, if you'd test out code before telling me it won't work, that would be appreciated on this side.  Hint: `ones(8)` is just there to replicate your block size, it has nothing to do with your label values.